# React Native: Why my text breaks like this and why is it not respecting the container margin?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I want to display multiple elements next to each other in React Native (with a flex wrap if there are too many elements or if the elements are too long). Each element consists of an icon and a text. If the text is too long, the text should break into the next line.

I tried different things with flexGrow and flexShrink but nothing had the desired effect. Here is my code ([expo snack](https://snack.expo.io/@raider/iconwithtext)):

```
export default function App() {

  function iconWithText(text) {
    return (
      <View style={styles.iconWithTextWrapper}>
        <View style={{paddingRight: 10, backgroundColor: 'grey'}}>
            <Text>Icon</Text>
        </View>
        <View style={{backgroundColor: 'yellow'}}>
          <Text>{text}</Text>
        </View>
      </View>
    )
  }

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      {iconWithText('short text')}
      {iconWithText('short text')}
      {iconWithText('this is a long, long, long text that does break very ugly')}
    </View>
  );
}



const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    marginTop: 50,
    marginHorizontal: 50,
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    flexWrap: 'wrap',
    justifyContent: 'flex-start',
  },
  iconWithTextWrapper: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
        margin: 10,
  }
});
```

Here is the corresponding result - as you can see the margin of the whole container is not respected and the text does not break very well:

[image: Text breaks ugly and margin not respected]

Why is the right margin of the container not respected, why does the text break like this and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding a `flex:1` to your text style.

edit:

I played around in your snack and came up with this:
https://snack.expo.io/@moistbobo/iconwithtext

Please see if this fits your use case.

Comment: You mean like this? `<Text style={{flex: 1}}>{text}</Text>`? That results in a non-breaking text - the text just goes right out of the container :-(.

Comment: @RaideR I made some changes to your snack, please have a look.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. The `maxWidth: '100%'` made the difference!